# Characters of Topological Group of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, topological-groups

I am seeking to show that if $\phi :\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a character of the topological group $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\phi$ must have the form $\phi(x)=e^{ix\cdot\xi}$ for some $\xi$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have had a thought to define a function $F(x)= \int_{B(0,|x|)}\phi(t)dt$ where $B(0,|x|)$ is the open ball at zero of radius $|x|$.

Then \begin{eqnarray}
 F(x+z) &=& \displaystyle\int_{B(0, |x+z|)} \phi(t)dt \\&=& \int_{B(0, |x|)} \phi(t)dt + \int_{B(0, |x+z|)\setminus B(0, |x|)} \phi(t)dt\\&=&F(x) +\int_{B(0, |z|)}\phi(t+x)dt 
\\&=&F(x) +\int_{B(0, |z|)} \phi(x)\phi(t)dt \;\;\;(\phi \text{ is a homomorphism})
\\&=&F(x) + \phi(x)F(z)
\end{eqnarray}

Since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, it must take the identity to the identity. so, $\phi(0) = 1$. Furthermore, since $\phi$ is continuous, there must be some $z$ such that $F(z) \not =0$.

From the above chain of equalities, we get the following:

$\phi(x) =\dfrac{F(x+z)-F(x)}{F(z)}$, implying that $\phi$ is differentiable.

Therefore for any $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}(x+y) = \phi(x)\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}(y).$

Set $y=0$ and let $k$ be equal to $\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}(0)$. So, we then have $\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}(x) = k\phi(x)$

We then have a differential equation. I want to use integrating factors of some sort, but my knowledge of PDEs is not the best.

Does the following hold?

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\phi(x) e^{-kx}) = (\dfrac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_i}(x)-k\phi(x))e^{-kx} = 0$ so that $\phi(x) e^{-kx}$ is constant. We can set $x=0$ to see that $\phi(x) e^{-kx} = 1$. Since we know that $|\phi(x)| = 1$, this then implies that $k = i \xi$ for some $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Does this show that every character of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a topological group must be of form $\phi(x)=e^{ix\cdot\xi}$?

Comment: If someone has a suggestion for a better method of showing the form of characters for the topological group, that also will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Show that a character on $f:R^n\to C^\times$ is a product of $n$ characters on $R$, $f_i:R\to C$ in the sense that $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=f_1(x_1)\cdots f_n(x_n)$. This reduces the whole thing to $R$. You then have to find the continuous homomorphisms $R\to C^\times$. Show that such a thing is actually of class $C^1$ and that it satisfies a first order linear ODE. Then use the uniqueness theorme for ODEs.